# how to properly format custom post type rewrite to get specific URL structure for archive and post views

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules

### The goal

I created a custom post type for events listing and want to achieve the following URL structures

**all archives url**

This url returns 404 error

```
https://example.com/events-list/
```

**single archive url**

This url returns correctly code 200

```
https://example.com/events-list/high-steppers-tour-dates/
```

**page url**

This url returns 404 error

```
https://example.com/events-list/high-steppers-tour-dates/the-concert-in-june
```

#### coding

```php
add_action('init', function() {

register_taxonomy('eventcal_cat','eventcal', [
'labels'            => $taxlabels, //taxonomy labels array
'public'            => true,
'hierarchical'      => true,
'show_ui'           => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var'         => true,
'rewrite'           => ['slug'=>'events-list','with_front'=>true]
]);

// post type
register_post_type('eventcal', [
'public'              => true,
'show_admin_column'   => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable'  => true,
'hierarchical'        => false,
'query_var'           => true,
'taxonomies'          => ['eventcal_cat'],
'supports'            => $support,// supports array
'labels'              => $labels,// labels array
'rewrite'             => ['slug'=>'events-list','with_front'=>true],
'has_archive'         => true
]);

});
```

I've tried many rewrite formats (re-saving permalinks setting per change) and none have delivered the desired results.

**what is the correct rewrite method or additional coding process to get the above indicated structuring?**